# Doesn't running containers inside vm's beat their purpose?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cloud, virtual-machine

I started looking more closely to kubernetes, containers and virtualization technologies since my employer has decided to move everything to Azure and AKS.

From what I understand, everything in AKS will be running [inside VM's.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#nodes-and-node-pools)

The same applies to GKE and EKS.
Amazon provides some bare metal instances but I am not sure whether this works with kubernetes.

Doesn't that hurt performance?
The promise of containers was that you run on a lighter virtualization layer instead on a full blown vm.

Doesn't running containers inside vm's beat the purpose?

Answer (score 4):

A (Linux) container is a set of 1 or more processes that are isolated from the rest of the system through [Linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces). Namespaces are a feature of the Linux kernel that partitions kernel resources (mounts, network devices etc) such that one set of processes sees one set of resources while another set of processes sees a different set of resources. For example, each container sees a different root file system (the container image) and its process tree is isolated from the rest of the process tree of the host.

Apart from being isolated through namespaces, the container is also limited in how much resources it can use by [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), also a feature of the Linux Kernel.

In other words, **containers aren't really "virtualization"**, since all it is using is native Kernel functionality and the overhead of using container (once started) is extremely small, once it is bootstrapped it runs just like any other process.

Kubernetes is a system for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications and it needs somewhere to host the containers. This infrastructure can be either bare metal or VM's.

**Thus running containerized applications inside a VM brings the same benefits as running them on bare metal (isolation and resource consumption limits)**. Whether to provide compute resources to the cluster through bare metal or VM's is another questions, each having its pros and cons, but **the pros and cons of VM's vs bare metal do not depend on whether you run containers or regular applications and processes** on them.

Your observation that AKS; GKE and EKS are using VM's to provide compute resources to the cluster is correct. It abstracts the physical hardware away  and is currently the standard way by public cloud providers to provide compute resources

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a popular debate in the community and has been going on for quite some time now.

I would say that it doesn't *really defeat the purpose per-se* but there are advantages and disadvantages of choosing one over the other.

If we were to look at this objectively, then some of the key deciding factors are:

- Performance
- Operational convenience (this is debatable whether the target hosting is on-premise or public cloud)
- Costs
- Definitely will be more ...

I've put together a couple of small tables to highlight some of the trade-offs and would like to invite the community members to add to this as well.

**Bare metal**

| Advantages | Disadvantages |
| --- | --- |
| More cost-effective as the Hyperviser licensing cost can be avoided | On the flip side, would miss out on advanced functionalities available through virtualisation |
| Better performance and more optimal use of resources | Operationally inconvenient - for example upgrades to bare metal could be long and difficult |

**Virtual machines**

| Advantages | Disadvantages |
| --- | --- |
| Workload migration could be much better between VMs is likely to be smooth due to the presence of virtualisation, hence this can be convenient operationally for carrying out major upgrades | The same virtualisation layer would consume resources and therefore not very cost-effective. It also adds an extra layer of tech support should things go wrong |
| Due to the isolation of resources through VM creation, possibility of security leaks gets reduced greatly | The downside of the same factor i.e. resource(s) isolation, is that any resources for example storage allocated to a VM could go remain unused in the times of peak demand |

The list of points above is only an indicator of the trade-offs and by no means exhaustive and it's important to consider the overall context of the infrastructure deployment for these decisions.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply.
I wouldn't consider running on bare metal but since kubernetes can work with vm's what not use it with only vm's and skip the containers completely?

Comment: Well. When you run K8s pods, they will basically house your applications in containers - which is where the container runtime comes in on top of the OS. I mean .. in bare metal, it will be Host OS, then Container runtime and then K8s pods and in VMs, it will be Host OS, then Hyperviser, then VM's guest OS, then container runtime, then K8s pods.

Comment: And in your pods is where your actual application will sit. So, a couple of extra layers if you use VMs.

Comment: If you add your comments to your answer I will then accept it as well.

Comment: The containers do not need a container runtime to run (they are just isolated and resource limited Linux processes). It is true that a container runtime is generally installed on top of the OS (or guest OS of a VM) to help with bootstrapping and starting containers, but once they run they run directly on the kernel, there is no extra (virtualization) layer introduced in between

Comment: @danielorn - kernel of the guest OS... right? I mean the OS in the VM? If a container gets destroyed after starting, will the runtime not be required if K8s wants to restart it?

Comment: @Lalit > Yes, Kernel of the guest OS. The container runtime will be needed for K8s to create a new pod. My point was more that the container runtime is not a layer that the "container runs on top of". The container is created through the container runtime, but runs on the guest OS (or guest Kernel if you like). As such, no "extra layer of virtualization" is added because of the containers

Comment: Ahh I see your point now. So, in the resource consumption argument I can remove the container runtime layer, I presume that's what you were hinting at. Although in my answer, I've tried to generalise this and included the bare metal option as well because in our organisation, we do have K8s running on bare metal.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Your comparison between bare metal and VM's are valid, but the OP asks if "running containers inside vm's beat the purpose", which it does not in my opinion. No one would claim VM's loose their utility because the application runs in as a process on a VM (just like it would on bare metal) and since containers are just isolated processes they don't beat the purpose of VM's, they bring something extra to the table.